# editing html with embedded PHP using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, onclick

I hope someone has an answer for me,

I am currently trying to create a PHP product page for my shop website, I have an sql table that stores the name of an image prefix eg if the image file is 'test_1.png' then the table stores 'test'. using embedded php

```
src="images/shop/<?php echo $row['item_img'], '_1.png';?>"></img>
```

what I would like to do is using js, dynamically update the src on a mouse click.

something like eg.

```
var imgSwitch = function(i){
  Document.getElementById('js-img').src = "images/shop/
    <?php echo $row['item_img'], '_';?>i<?php echo '.png';?>";
}
```

Even to me this seems wrong which is why I've turned to the GURU's here

Is there anyway this would be possible? If not, any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: `Document` => `document`.

Comment: What is displayed when you have `src="images/shop/<?php echo $row['item_img'], '_1.png';?>"></img>` I am wondering

Comment: fyi @joyBlanks it is one image of the product displayed, think of a thumbnail, if you click on it, the main image is replaced by that of the thumbnail, so you get to see multiple angles of the product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to figure out what you are asking, and I think this is your way to go:

```
var imgSwitch = function(i){
  document.getElementById('js-img').src = "images/shop/<?php echo $row['item_img'], '_';?>" + i + ".png";
}
```

The change is in the i, you have to cut the string and add it as a variable.

But remember that the PHP code is executed at the server, and will not change once the page is sent to the client. When you execute that function, $row['item_img'] will always be the same.

Comment: YES, this is exactly what I wanted, thank you, I shall try that now

Comment: Note that this only works if all images that you may be 'switching' should be of the same image prefix from the DB. Otherwise, you may define separate javascript functions for the various prefix-types.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example which you can adapt. What I do in the code below is give the element an `id` and attach an `onclick` to it.

In the function we pass the `id` as a parameter (`onclick(changeSrc(this.id))`) and we manipulate the src using the `getElementById` as we have the `id`.

```
<img src="http://ladiesloot.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/smiley-face-1-4-15.png" id="test" onclick="changeSrc(this.id);" height="400" width="400" />

<script>
function changeSrc(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).src = "http://i0.wp.com/www.compusurf.es/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/smiley.jpeg?fit=1200%2C1200";
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tq1Lq5at/

**Edit 1**

You're using `Document` when it should be `document`, notice the lowercase **d**.

Comment: You could also only pass `this` over the function so then you don't have to use `document.getElementById(id).src = ` and just use `obj.src = ` just to make things nice and clean :)